# How to limit user interaction to an area inside UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, gesture

Here is a UIView, which is the yellow rectangle, and I override the drawRect: method to draw the red area, and I added the UITapGesture etc. but I just wanna to respond the red area, if the user click inside the yellow rectangle, but not on the red area, I will not respond it. Do I need to manually get the position and calculate whether it is inside the scope? Any smartier way to do so? Thanks. [image]

Comment: If you don't need the yellow rectangle, what you could do instead of overriding the `drawRect` method is simply rotate the UIView and add a gesture recognizer to the view. Or create two views, and have the innermost view respond to touches. That might be easier.

Comment: I think, It will be easily you create you red rectangle as a view, rotate this view redRectangleView 45 degree. And add to this view the gesture. But there is several approach.

Comment: Instead of overriding drawrect method in uiview and writing logic for get touch coordinates. Try to add other view with red filled color in uiview with yellow border. It will simplify your logic as you only need to add gesture on red view.

Comment: draw a CGPath that matches the red area and use CGPathContainsPoint for the hit detection

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27149259/3804019

Comment: If you want to depending on color then fetch color at particular position and compare which view is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I know of is implementing the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method and verifying if your touch is inside / outside the red rectangle.